# how to ignore DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc for some fields like date of birth

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I get many datetime fields and I am converting them to UTC before process in Startup.cs but I want to ignore some fields to be converted to UTC like DOB. how to ignore some fields. Do i need to put any attribute or some thing so I can take dob as it is without converting to UTC.

> Startup.cs relevant code

```
var builder = services.AddMvc();
builder.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    // for UTC for datetime
    options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
    IsoDateTimeConverter dateConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'"
    };
    //options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(dateConverter);
});
```

> Class which have dob field

```
[DataContract(Name = "Patient")]
public class Patient
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public Guid PatientId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Man, try to remove this lines `options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;     IsoDateTimeConverter dateConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter    {        DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'"    };`
Everywhere it will ne needed, the date will be converted to UTC date.

Comment: I want utc date but not for all fields. If I remove those lines then it will be applicable for all.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to make those specific datetime objects to have no timezone.  In their `set` method, you could set their timezone to be UTC or set their offset to be zero.

Comment: But I like Jake Steffen's answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this decorator:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'")]
```

Comment: I tried 
     [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "yyyy'- 
     'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'")]
      public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

still not working..

Comment: If i give 01/01/2000 it takes it to 1 day back, 31/12/1999