# Override global newtonsoft serialization options

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

In my ASP.NET Core app, I have the following setup in `Startup`:

```cs
services.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
    options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy/MM/dd"; // <-- HERE

});
```

The line marked with "HERE" comment sets a global way of handling `DateTime` serialization. This is what I need in 99% of the cases. However, I have an endpoint where I do not want to format dates this way and I want to retain time information as well (in ISO format for example). Is there any way to override the global setting somehow for specific endpoint or model?

I tried applying `[JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]` attribute to my model's `DateTime` properties, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429027/how-to-ignore-datetimezonehandling-utc-for-some-fields-like-date-of-birth

Comment: @MCLinkTimeError As I see, there's no definitive answer, but I'll check this out anyway.

Comment: @MCLinkTimeError, that issue does not answer my question unfortunately

Comment: `[JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]` is not working when applied to specific properties because `JsonTextReader` has already recognized the incoming JSON strings as `DateTime` objects.  To prevent that, you can add `[JsonConverter(typeof(DateParseHandlingConverter), DateParseHandling.None)]` to your model, where `DateParseHandlingConverter` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631270/3744182) to [Json.NET deserializing DateTimeOffset value fails for DateTimeOffset.MinValue without timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50628374/3744182).

Comment: But that's kind of a workaround, it would be cleaner to control the settings per endpoint as your question asks.  What precise version of asp.net / asp.net core are you using?  The answer will depend on the version, I suspect.  For instance, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52623772/3744182) by Kirk Larkin to [Change the JSON serialization settings of a single ASP.NET Core controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52605946/3744182).

Comment: Also, do you need to control settings just for serialization, or also for model binding / deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was applying the attribute wrong. I'm using records.
Instead of doing that:

```cs
public record Abc(
   [JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
   DateTime DateTime)
```

I should have done that:

```cs
public record Abc(
   [property: JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
   DateTime DateTime)
```

That way, the attribute gets applied to the property, and not constructor parameter. My record gets serialized with ISO time format, even though the global setting is different.